# WPF binding to a non dependency property on a control template

Tags: wpf, templates, binding

I'm creating a WPF custom control as an auto learning exercise. My control has a ListView inside the template. I wanto my control user be able on defining the needed columns in his own Xaml, but I did not get the strategy on how to pass the columns to the inner listview since binding with FindAncestor complain that "Columns" is not a DependencyProperty. 
Wekk the questions are:

1. How to achieve bind a property from xaml to the template when it is not a DP
2. Correct my design: I think there is something wrong: if someone would change completely my template, how should I let him use the Column collection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not inherit from ListView directly? Then you have all the properties you need for the ListView and can also add you own properties to the class.

Then you can apply a custom Style to your control to make it look like you want. ([Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747.aspx) you have a basic ListView Style that you can use and expand to your needs)

Comment: this is an option, and maybe it reply to the question 2) correct my design ;) but since it is a learning exercise, can't we try to figure out a solution anyway ? O really there is no way ?

Comment: @Felice there surely are ways, but they definately involve code in one form or another. To get the inner ListView to take on the Columns you would need either 1: code that directly assigns these on change of the outer Columnproperties, or 2: an Attached DependencyProperty/Behavior on the ListView that is used to bind to the outer ColumnProperty (haven't looked too thorough, but couldn't actually find if someone has done that before)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes binding to a property that is not a dependency property can be solved using [the Binding Mode OneWayToSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

Have you tried that?

Comment: I did'nt, but now I've already turned out to the ListView inheritance. It is good to know, in any case.